# Unable to split string

Tags: java, string

I have a string `002999002020` which I want to split and get a result `992020`. I have tried following

```
String[] s1 = selectedMeterNo.split(String.valueOf(4),2);
String[] s2 = selectedMeterNo.split(String.valueOf(9),3);
```

The output of `s1` and `s2` is empty.

Comment: `992020` is not a substring of `002999002020` .. Whats the use case of this operation you want to perform  ?

Comment: @ADM `002999002020` is the serial number. I am sending a request in which the serial number ID is passed. Each serial number ID is taken out from its serial number i.e. `002999002020 => 992020' and vice versa. I thing I have to split the string into two and then combine/concat them ?

Comment: The `split` function won't do you any good in this case, you'll have to manually extract the substring by finding the indices where it begins and ends. Also, as @ADM said, `992020` is not really a substring of `002999002020`. I think you have to explain your problem a little clearer.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue better. How exactly would some derive this output from your input ? Split doesn't look like the right choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try substring.

```
String s1 = selectedMeterNo.substring(4,6);
String s2 = selectedMeterNo.substring(9,12);
String s3 = s1+s2;
```

Comment: It throws `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 9, end 4, length 12`

Comment: Edited sorry. I forget change 4